# Google fonts not rendering with Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Having an issue where I'm trying to add in google fonts to a tailwind file, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work. Have followed multiple tutorials and they all show slightly different ways of doing this but none of them work. Have restarted my config file multiple times from scratch and re-done all the HTML & CSS files too.

The weird thing is when I hover over the utility class in the HTML, the popup shows that the class is changing the font family property but it simply doesn't when I refresh the live server.

Here is my HTML & config below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Arvo&family=Inter:wght@200;400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="text-xl font-std">test font 1</div>
    <div class="text-xl font-alt">test font 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,css}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        std: ["Inter", "sans-serif"],
        alt: ["Arvo", "serif"],
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Can u publish your code on codesandbox? We can debug that

Answer (score 0):

`fontFamily` is not child of `extend`:

try:

```
theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      std: ["Inter", "sans-serif"],
      alt: ["Arvo", "serif"],
    }
  },
```

example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/sEmrhTsuEJ?file=config

Comment: Thanks - it ended up fixing itself somehow, I definitely tried having 'fontFamily' within and outside of 'extend'. Nothing but issues with Tailwind so far!